# How to sum a row and a column in a list of lists?

Tags: python, list

Given

```
X =  [[3, 2, 3, 2], [3, 2, 2, 3],[3, 2, 2, 2], [3, 2, 2, 10], [3, 3, 3, 3]]
```

How could I write a function in python that gives me the sum of the values of a column (the same of first values of each inside list) and a row (the same of the values of one inside list)

Comment: It's not clear what you mean be sum of column **and** row. Are you trying to add rows and columns, or are you trying to get two different things? What output are you expecting from the given list?

Comment: do you mind using `numpy` or `pandas`?

Comment: sorry, for example in the sum row [0] i would expect 10, and in sum column [0] i would expect 15

Answer (score 2):

You can use `zip(*some_list_of_lists)` to iterate over the columns of the sublists. Note, however, that this will give you sums up to the length of the shortest sublist. If you have uneven lists, you can use [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) with a default value of zero.

```
l = [[3, 2, 3, 2], [3, 2, 2, 3],[3, 2, 2, 2], [3, 2, 2, 10], [3, 3, 3, 3]] 

columns_sums = [sum(col) for col in zip(*l)]
# [15, 11, 12, 20]
```

For the sum of rows you can just use a regular list comprehension and take the `sum()` of each item:

```
row_sums = [sum(row) for row in l]
# [10, 10, 9, 17, 12]
```

Answer (score 1):

Giving your input represents the matrix row by row (`[3, 2, 3, 2]` is a first row, `[3, 3, 3, 3, 3]` is a first column) you can do it either by iterating the rows, getting n-th value from the list and summing them up:

```
def sum_n_column(n, matrix):
     res = 0
     for arr in matrix:
             res += arr[n]
     return res
```

Or, using [functools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html):

```
from functools import reduce

def sum_n_column(n, matrix):
    return reduce((lambda x, y: x + y), [x[n] for x in matrix])
```

This, actually can be simplified to:

```
def sum_n_column(n, matrix):
    return sum([x[n] for x in matrix])
```

In all functions, `n` means the number of the column to sum and `matrix` should contain an array of arrays, like in the example variable you provided.

EDIT: To get sum of the row (sum of all values in the array), do:

```
def sum_n_row(n, matrix):
    res = 0
    for i in matrix[n]:
        res += matrix[n][i]
    return res
```

or, the easy way:

```
def sum_n_row(n, matrix):
    return sum(matrix[n])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_sum(arr, indx, ax=0):
    if ax==0:
        return sum(arr[indx])
    return sum(a[indx] for a in arr)

arr = [[3, 2, 3, 2], [3, 2, 2, 3],[3, 2, 2, 2], [3, 2, 2, 10], [3, 3, 3, 3]]
get_sum(arr, 0, 1)
```